# Problems with ASP.NET recaptcha and JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, recaptcha

I want to have a Recaptcha on a JQuery Dialog. Though the line

```
$("#newsletterDialog").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: true, 
    modal: false, 
    resizable: false, 
    draggable: false, 
    width: 400 
})
```

Will break jquery, so that

```
validator.Challenge = Context.Request.Form[RECAPTCHA_CHALLENGE_FIELD];
```

fails (I.e. some operation with a hidden field foes wrong). In addition Firefox is hanging, so I cant debug the way I am used to (I think that's not just because of that line).

Any clues?

Comment: Can you provide an example page or html that we can test? I can't discern the problem simply from your description.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the specific Firefox issues were solved by not having

```
$("#newsletterDialog").dialog inside    $(document).ready(function())
```

(I.e it is executed immediately instead of in a later event )

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is an iframe with the captcha-code inside the dialog DIV.
It makes some programming  more difficult though (Having to go up to the parent document).